# Typeahead search with Post ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

This is my sample data that I am getting through **POST** api call that I have to use in typeahead search in MVC View.

```
{
    "MyWrapper": {
        "lstCourses": [
            {
                "CourseId": 1,
                "CourseName": "BCA"
            },
            {
                "CourseId": 2,
                "CourseName": "MCA"
            },
            {
                "CourseId": 3,
                "CourseName": "Btech"
            },
            {
                "CourseId": 4,
                "CourseName": "Mtech"
            },
            {
                "CourseId": 5,
                "CourseName": "MCom"
            },
            {
                "CourseId": 6,
                "CourseName": "Phd"
            },
            {
                "CourseId": 7,
                "CourseName": "Physics"
            },
            {
                "CourseId": 8,
                "CourseName": "philosophy"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to show course name in typeahead search and for this I a using *typeaahead.js* and *bloodhound*

This is my html code and my issue is CourseNames are not coming as suggestions in text box.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/typeaahead.js"></script>
<div id="bloodhound">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>

<script>


    var courses = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

        remote: {
            url: 'http://localhost:54518/api/Myapi#%QUERY',
           wildcard: '%QUERY',
            transport: function (opts, onSuccess, onError) {
                var url = opts.url.split("#")[0];
                var query = opts.url.split("#")[1];
                var result;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: "value=" + query,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (data) { return data.MyWrapper.lstCourses; },
                        error: onError,
                    })


            }
        }
    });

    courses.initialize();
    $('input').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'courses',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: courses,
        templates: {
            empty: [
             '<div class="empty-message">',
             'no results found',
             '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function (data) {
                console.log (data);
                return '<p><strong>' + data.CourseId + '  </strong> - ' + data.CourseName + '</p>';

            }
        }


    });




</script>
```

Main issue I am facing in handling nested objects to set as source.Can anyone please put me on right path?any relevant links?

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason for using a POST instead of a GET?

Comment: I have to use a third party api and they are providing only POST calls

Comment: @whipdancer Can you help on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320812/duplicate-records-coming-in-typeahead-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two things that might fix it for you.

You can try changing the initialization for the typeahead so that the display key is a property in your data:

```
name: 'courses',
displayKey: 'CourseName',
source: courses,
```

You can also try adding a `filter` method to the `remote`. I use the filter method in my remote options to change the dataset I get to something more easily used by the typeahead:

```
remote: {
        filter: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                return $.map(data, function (object) {
                    return { id: object.id, value: object.name};
                });
            } else {
                return {};
            }
        }
    }
```

In your case, you would need to check the data you are returning and probably use `data.MyWrapper.lstCourses`.  But that is something you can easily check using the dev tools in your browser.  If you use the filter method, you can leave your `displayKey` setting as "value".